# LibUSB ErrNo 16 Resource Busy - Magstripe reader

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyusb, libusb-1.0

I am using a rPi 2B to which I have plugged in a Magstripe Card Reader (using a PS/2 to USB converter). I determined the correct Vendor/Product ID's using lsusb and then am using the following code which uses libusb to connect to the reader. This code does the check for `is_kernel_driver_active` that seems to be the main source of error for this problem. Code is from the [keyboard_alike](https://github.com/riklaunim/pyusb-keyboard-alike/blob/master/keyboard_alike/reader.py) project on github.

```
def initialize(self):
    self._device = usb.core.find(idVendor=self.vendor_id, idProduct=self.product_id)

    if self._device is None:
        raise DeviceException('No device found, check vendor_id and product_id')

    if self._device.is_kernel_driver_active(self.interface):
        try:
            self._device.detach_kernel_driver(self.interface)
        except usb.core.USBError as e:
            raise DeviceException('Could not detach kernel driver: %s' % str(e))

    try:
        self._device.set_configuration()
        if self.should_reset:
            self._device.reset()
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        raise DeviceException('Could not set configuration: %s' % str(e))

    self._endpoint = self._device[0][(0, 0)][0]
```

When executed as root, I get a `Resource busy` on the call to `self._device.set_configuration()`.

I have run all the updates and I am not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have fixed this using this [post](https://projectgus.com/2014/09/blacklisting-a-single-usb-device-from-linux/) - it looks like the problem is that the Magstripe Reader was being claimed by the USBHID driver at start up. This issue is not resolved using `detach_kernel_driver()`.

I created a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d` to keep this device from being loaded. I am now on to a new problem but this appears to have corrected the initial problem.

My Rule looked like this: 
    # Magstripe reader should be disabled 
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2324", ATTR{authorized}="0"